# Flutter: TextField's prefix icon still showing when its parent's Container is set to 0

Tags: flutter

```
AnimatedContainer(
  height: open ? 300 : 0,
  width: open ? 750 : 0,
  duration:
      Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 20, 42, 165),
    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
      Radius.circular(10),
    ),
  ),
  curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
  child: Center(
    child: TextField(
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.email,
          color: Colors.orangeAccent,
        ),
        ),
        border: InputBorder.none,
        labelText: 'email',
        labelStyle: _spStyleGet.labelStyle,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

I have this `AnimatedContainer`. When the container is not opened, I can still see that email icon inside the TextField. It is impossible to hide it. Also, I tried to set the condition to make it appear when the container is opened. It showed up from the right side of the container which makes it  very unnatural.

Additionally, I switched the AnimatedContainer to just normal Container. Still, have the same problem.

Comment: Well the quick fix will be to add a ternary operator on `prefixIcon` which is your `open`. But its weird that icon is inside textfield but yet its still showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in Flutter, "layout" and "painting" are two separate steps in the rendering pipeline. A widget with a size of zero during the layout phase, does not necessarily mean it won't paint anything on the screen.

If you want to prevent a widget from painting anything outside of its supposed size, you can use `ClipRect` widget. However, this feature is also built-in to `Container` (and `AnimatedContainer`) already. So in your case, you can simply:

**Add `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge` to your `AnimatedContainer`.**

Answer (score 0):

You can set bool like below for icon also.

```
AnimatedContainer(
          height: open ? 300 : 0,
          width: open ? 750 : 0,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 20, 42, 165),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(10),
            ),
          ),
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          child: Center(
            child: TextField(
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: open
                    ? Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.email,
                          color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                        ),
                      )
                    : Container(),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                labelText: 'email',
                // labelStyle: _spStyleGet.labelStyle,
            ),
         ),
      ),
  )
```

Comment: This was what i did. However, the icon came out of nowhere to the container when the container was opened. user1032613's answer was the answer that I was looking for but cheers mate!